# Git graph log of only a few commits

Tags: git, logging, graph, commit

I've for example a few commits:

- v1.2.3 (tag)
- master (branch)
- release/1.2 (branch)
- 12345af (SHA-1 of a commit)
- ...

Is it possible to have graph log linking those that would let me quickly see the order and relations. Something like:

```
* f000000 - (master) Blabla
| ...
|\
| | ...
| * f000000 - (refs/remotes/origin/release/1.2) Blabla
| | ...
* | 12345af - Blabla
| | ...
| * f000000 - (refs/tags/v1.2.3) Blabla
```

How to **hide** the other commits (unlike simple `git --graph --online ...`). There is `git branch --contains ...` which helps a lot but doesn't tell if a tag is before or after a commit, and/or if a tag "contains" that commit.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the switch "--simplify-by-decoration" ? With this switch only commits related to a branch or tag are shown.

Comment: It's a nice helper but doesn't answer the question (which may have no answers at this time). We just have too many tags and quiet some branches.